# Get Netbeans to recogzine HTML tags in PHP HEREDOC

Tags: php, netbeans, heredoc

I've tried Googling this, but I cannot find any information on it.  Is there a way to get Netbeans to recognize the HTML tags inside HEREDOC as HTML tags?  For example, if I do:

```
echo <<<EOHTML
<table>
  <tr></tr>
EOHTML;
```

Netbeans does not complain about this or say that you probably want to close the table tag as it would in the HTML editor.  Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: It's a [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=125684)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented bug in NetBeans: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=125684

Comment: That bug seems to be only relevant for PHP code, which does work.  I'm talking about HTML syntax.

Comment: As I read through the bug report, it seems that the bug refers to both strings and heredoc blocks (to include syntax highlighting of both php and html code).

Comment: I don't think so.  It's clearly listed as a requested feature here: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194149

Comment: And thank you for showing me this site!  Did not think to look through their Bugzilla.

Comment: As an aside, why use `echo <<<EOHTML ... HTML;` in the first place? Why not `?> <table><tr><?= $data ?></tr></table> <?php`?

Comment: All I did was google "netbeans php heredoc syntax highlighting".

Comment: Because OCD doesn't allow me to have opening and closing PHP tags anywhere but the beginning and ending of a file.

Comment: Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder? That must SUCK reading other people's code!